# How to add a list view dynamically using JqueryMobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing an application and im using jQuery mobile for the UI. Did any body know how to implement list view dynamically  using js. The static code snippet is below:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="g"> 
      <li><a href="acura.html">Acura</a></li> 
      <li><a href="audi.html">Audi</a></li> 
      <li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Nobody posted the page in the jQuery Mobile documentation, so here it is: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/lists/docs-lists.html. It tells you how to do what you want on the bottom of the page, under `Updating lists`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this way:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="g" id="lstSample">

</ul>
```

In js

```
    for(var i=0;i<urs_source.length;i++){
        $("#lstSample").append($("<li><a href='" + urs_source[i].link + "'>" + urs_source[i].text  + "</a></li>"));
}

$('#lstSample').listview('refresh');
```

Finally you need to refresh your list view.

Comment: This is a bad way to add elements to the DOM. You should buffer the output and do a single append to the DOM. Just create a string/array outside the loop, then each iteration add to the string/array. After the loop runs select the list and append the concocted string (or concoct a string from the array by using `arr.join('')`). The point here is that you shouldn't do work inside of a loop that you can do outside it because you're then doing that work over and over rather than once. You're selecting the element every itaration as well as appending to the DOM, both can happen outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="g" id="mylist"> 
      <li><a href="acura.html">Acura</a></li> 
      <li><a href="audi.html">Audi</a></li> 
      <li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li> 
</ul>
```

```
$("#mylist").css("display","none");
$("#mylist").css({display:"none", backgroundColor:"red"});
```

This should help.

Comment: how to implement listbox dynamically

Answer (score 0):

So you wanna add li elements to your ui element?

if so you can do something like this:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="g" id="mylist"> 
      <li><a href="acura.html">Acura</a></li> 
      <li><a href="audi.html">Audi</a></li> 
      <li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li> 
</ul>
```

---

```
function addlist(link, text) {
$("#mylist").append("<li><a href='" + link + "'>" + text + "</a></li>");
}
```

---

And then you can add list items calling the function like this:

```
addlist("ford.html", "Ford");
```

Else i dont get your question :-(

Answer (score 0):

After adding elements to the list using JS; you need to invoke [`refresh`](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/lists/lists-methods.html) on it to let JQM enhance it.

```
$('.selector').listview('refresh');
```